# confirm message when onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask confirm message when onclick

Here is my code:

```
$('#activate').click(function() { 
var url='<?php echo getStoreURL($_REQUEST['key']); ?>admin/email_tracker.php';
var key='<?php echo $data['api_key'];?>'

 $.post(url, {  key:key, activate:1 } );
 alert('Store activated');
 location.reload(true);
});
```

Here I need an alert box are you sure you want to active?. How to do it?. Thanks

Comment: look at your generated source code to make sure the PHP part has ran as expected. This will tell you if your problems exist in PHP or JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#activate').click(function() { 

  var url='<?php echo getStoreURL($_REQUEST['key']); ?>admin/email_tracker.php';
  var key='<?php echo $data['api_key'];?>'

  if(!confirm("Your message")){ return;  }


  $.post(url, {  key:key, activate:1 } );
  alert('Store activated');
  location.reload(true);
});
```

**[PROCEDURAL DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9BYHX/)**

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('#activate').click(function() {
  var Confirm = confirm("Are you sure?");
  if (Confirm == true) {
    //put your function here
  }
});
```